# Montar aplicacion nodejs en windows server 2008 r2

Tags: nodejs, windows-server

Realice una aplicacion en nodejs y ahora necesito montarla al servidor. ya insetale nodejs y el iisnode e instale el archivo de prueba, pero no logro que me ejecute la aplicacion, siempre me aparece un error 404 y ya no se que mas hacer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el archivo `web.config` le estoy pasando el app.js

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    to be handled by the iisnode module -->

    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

y este es el app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
var index = require('./routes/routes');
var passport = require('passport');
require('./passport/passport')(passport);

var app = express();

// Setting Base directory
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//CORS Middleware
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    //Enabling CORS 
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, contentType,Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
});


app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(flash());

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Conectar passport con la aplicacion
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/', index);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: ¿Estás siguiendo algún tutorial?

Comment: Hice el tutoria para instalar el iisnode.

Comment: Quizás debas mover la carpeta de tu proyecto a C:/inetpub/wwwroot/